# Decorators syntax in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I don't understand most things about the next code (it's from the typescript handbook):

```
function classDecorator<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
  constructor: T
) {
  return class extends constructor {
    newProperty = "new property";
    hello = "override";
  };
}

@classDecorator
class Greeter {
  property = "property";
  hello: string;
  constructor(m: string) {
    this.hello = m;
  }
}

console.log(new Greeter("world"));
```

Why in `<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>`, `T` extends an "object¿?"? What is exactly what T is extending?

And why that function is returning a class that extends the constructor? I'm very confused and I have trying to understand that 2 days. Thanks.

Comment: `{ new (...args: any[]): {} }` is a type literal for values that implement `new`, i.e. which are constructor functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript a `class` *is* a constructor, that is, a class is an object that you can `new`.

The syntax for defining a constructor in a class definition is not actually a defining a member of the class, it is just a way to specify parameters and, optionally perform some initialization in an organized manner.

The `new` keyword predates the ES2015 `class` syntax some two decades, before the introduction of which "classes" were witten as

```
function Greeter(m: string) { }
```

And instantiated using `new Greeter("hi")`.

That is, you wrote a constructor function, and that is what a class was and largely still is.

When the `class` syntax was added in ES2015, it was designed, for the most part, as a more declarative syntactic sugar for the existing constructor function pattern.

Now, with that context, we can get to the meat of your question.

The constraint on `T` says that it must be a constructor, that is something that can be `new`ed, and that is a `class`.

Such a type can be written several ways in TypeScript

As in the example:

```
{ new (...args: any[]): {} }
```

Describes an object that can called with `new`, passing zero or more parameters, that is a class, and that is a constructor.

For clarification, compare this with the type of an object that can be called without `new`

```
{ (...args: any[]): {} }
```

The above describes an object that can called without `new`, passing zero or more parameters, that it a function.

In modern TypeScript an alternative syntax is usually preferred as it is more concise and expressive

```
new (...args: any[]) => {}
```

For a for a class/constructor and

```
(...args: any[]) => {}
```

For a function.

As to the decorator's return value, it is leveraging a capability of class decorators to replace the class itself with another class. Class decorators can modify their target or, as we see in this case, replace it my returning a new class.

Comment: But if the decorator returns another constructor, the new constructor for the class will be the constructor that the decorator returned? And if the decorator don't return anything, the constructor for the class will be the same?

Comment: That's almost correct. It is replacing the entire class. As I attempted to emphasize, the class and the constructor are one and the same. If it doesn't return anything, the class will not be replaced but the decorator could still modify the class in place, Say by adding a method

Comment: Oh, I see.. But why I can not replace <T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }> with T: Function?

Comment: Typescript tries to help you avoid common errors like forgetting to use the `new` operator on a constructor function or extending a function that isn't meant to be a constructor. Therefore, it differentiates between types that can be called and types that can be called with `new`. So while the following JavaScript is valid `function f() {} new f()`, TypeScript will complain because the type it gives to a function doesn't include a `new (args): any` call signature. While you could bypass that with a type assertion, you should use the more explicit type that denotes a constructor.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks you very much :)